# ImportError: No module named flask.ext.uploads

Tags: python, flask, importerror

I made a web server with Flask and python, and at one point I use Flask-Uploads. When I ran it, it worked originally, but when I moved it to another computer, it didn't work even though I installed all the packages correctly with pip. I have looked online for this error, and have found many solutions, but none of them work for me. If anyone has a way that could possibly help me, it would be greatly appreciated. The code that is getting the error is:

```
from flask.ext.uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads, IMAGES
```

And I get the error:

```
ImportError: No module named flask.ext.uploads
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install flask uploads module

```
pip install flask-uploads

from flask_uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads
```

Comment: Thank you. This fixed the problem of the ImportError, but now I am getting a permissions error, I don't think these are related though so thank you.